# How do I combine 4 images using alpha_composite?

Tags: python-3.x, python-imaging-library, nft

I am running into and issue where I receive and error message that my images do not match when everything looks like it is okay. I have searched all over the internet and understand how to do at least 2 images but 4 images is not working.

Here is my code:

```
#### Generate Images    
for item in all_images:

im1 = Image.open(f'./trait-layers/backgrounds/{background_files[item["Background"]]}.jpg').convert('RGBA')
im2 = Image.open(f'./trait-layers/elephants/{elephant_files[item["Elephant"]]}.png').convert('RGBA')
im3 = Image.open(f'./trait-layers/hats/{hat_files[item["Hat"]]}.png').convert('RGBA')
im4 = Image.open(f'./trait-layers/smoke/{smoke_files[item["Smoke"]]}.png').convert('RGBA')

#Create each composite
com1 = Image.alpha_composite(im1, im2)
com2 = Image.alpha_composite(com1, im3)
com3 = Image.alpha_composite(com2, im4)



#Convert to RGB
rgb_im = com3.convert('RGB')
file_name = str(item["tokenId"]) + ".png"
rgb_im.save("./images/" + file_name)
```

I get this error message:

```
  ValueError: images do not match
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
/var/folders/lq/nw0y9p2s6dnglsnqyls1d4qc0000gn/T/ipykernel_93566/2413409998.py in <module>
      9     #Create each composite
     10     com1 = Image.alpha_composite(im1, im2)
---> 11     com2 = Image.alpha_composite(com1, im3)
     12     com3 = Image.alpha_composite(com2, im4)
     13 

/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/site-packages/PIL/Image.py in alpha_composite(im1, im2)
   3042     im1.load()
   3043     im2.load()
-> 3044     return im1._new(core.alpha_composite(im1.im, im2.im))
   3045 
   3046 

ValueError: images do not match
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to make sure all image files are the same

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-ask).

Answer (score 0):

check also the dimensions. All image files should have the same size.