# Pasting transparent image over background using PIL/Pillow

Tags: python, python-imaging-library, png

I am trying to make an image partially transparent and then superimpose it over a second image. For example, take [this image](https://i.ibb.co/Z6nmCW5/circle.png) and set it to 50% transparency and then past it over [this image](https://i.ibb.co/W2Gf0Mq/one.png) to create [this composite image](https://i.ibb.co/ZL4xVBy/result.png). I've tried to do this with the following code:

```
from PIL import Image

background = Image.open("one.png")
foreground = Image.open("circle.png")
foreground.putalpha(120) # Sets the oval to 50% transparency
background.paste(foreground, (0, 0)) # Paste oval over the background
background.show()
```

However, when I try this it only shows the foreground. Is it possible to adjust transparency using PIL/Pillow this way to achieve the desired composite image?

Comment: see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68822679/how-do-i-combine-4-images-using-alpha-composite use  img3= Image.alpha_composite(im1, im2)

Answer (score 5):

I do not know how "putalpha" works, but for a similar problem of overlaying a png image with transparent background, what I just learned in a course is, that the png image has to be the mask, too. Like this:

```
from PIL import Image

background = Image.open("one.png")
foreground = Image.open("circle.png")
foreground.putalpha(120) # Sets the oval to 50% transparency
background.paste(foreground, (0, 0),mask=foreground) 
# Paste oval over the background
# use oval as mask
background.show()
```